# Changing accent behaviour to match iOS

Tags: macos, ios, keyboard, snow-leopard

In iOS an accent can be added after the character where it is intended. In OSX it is the opposite, it must be entered before. This means that if I forget to add it, I must delete the character, add the accent and then retype the character.

This makes fixing errors in OSX cumbersome and slow. Is there any way to change the behaviour of OSX to match that of iOS?

Many thanks.

EDIT: It is Greek I am trying to type so I've included Greek as the Input Source. I am also using Snow Leopard, in case this makes a difference...

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what keyboard set up you use, US ?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make a custom keyboard layout using

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Another option might be to use system preferences/language & text/text/symbol and text substitution to set up substitutions for the input of the base character plus ' generating the accented character.  But I no longer have 10.6 and can't remember if this feature is present there.

Comment: Thx. I've taken a look and at first glance it doesn't seem to do what I want. I'll try contacting the authors to be sure...

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be done by setting up the vowel characters as dead keys, so you enter them first and then the accent.  The Apple Vietnamese keyboard works this way.  But I think the opposite (entering the accent key before the vowel) is standard for all other Latin scripts and Greek on laptop/desktop machines.

Comment: I contacted the developers of Ukelele and they suggested what Tom did above. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem entirely. I still cannot go back to a word and simply add a missing accent. I must delete the character first and re-enter it. :(

Comment: The option using symbol and text substitution should let you go back to add accents, if your OS supports that.